# Can a AWS PostgresSQL RDS instance be provided with a stop words file?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, amazon-rds

I need to provide a custom list of stop words. From the [manual section on dictionaries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) the way to do this is to put a stopwords file in `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/`.

Is it possible to do this when using AWS? If no, can the stopwords file be provided over the command line instead?

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL 10

It does just that, you can [see the code here,](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/tsearch/ts_utils.c#L68)

```
void
readstoplist(const char *fname, StopList *s, char *(*wordop) (const char *))
{
    char      **stop = NULL;

    s->len = 0;
    if (fname && *fname)
    {
        char       *filename = get_tsearch_config_filename(fname, "stop");
        tsearch_readline_state trst;
        char       *line;
        int         reallen = 0;
```

`**stop` could be modified easily to read from the yet-nonexistant parameters, but currently it just pulls from the file. A few lines above and you'll find [`get_tsearch_config_filename(fname,extension)`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/tsearch/ts_utils.c#L33) which looks in just the place you were referring too,

```
snprintf(result, MAXPGPATH, "%s/tsearch_data/%s.%s",
         sharepath, basename, extension);
```

There is nothing else in the code base that writes to a `StopList` pointer. **As of PostgreSQL 10, it's not possible.**

## Amazon RDS

There is an [unresolved issue from 2014 on AWS Developer for this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=626892),

Amazon confirms we're right in saying there is no way

> Unfortunately, because RDS doesn't provide filesystem access, you won't be able to upload your custom files to $SHAREDIR.

And Amazon follows up with

> I have raised a feature request with the RDS team.